# Axios - Dynamic Header not working. Why does my code not work when i set the variable dynamically but does when i hard code it?

Tags: javascript, authentication, axios

I can't seem to figure out how to get my 2nd http post to work "queuecallback".  It looks like the problem is specific to how i set the headers.  Headers = my_headers.  It works when i hard code it but not when i try to call it dynamically.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
const axios = require('axios');
const queuecallback = require('axios');

 var my_token;
 var my_formated_token;
 var my_headers;
 var myJSON;
   function connectToAgentHandler(agent) {
        axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://myapi.com/AuthorizationServer/Token',
          data: {
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword',
        grant_type: 'password'
            },
        headers: {'Authorization': 'basic 123456789Aghtiaqq111kkksksksk111'}
          }
        )
        .then((result) => {
           my_token = result.data.access_token;
          console.log("Token:", my_token);
          my_formated_token = 'bearer ' + my_token;
          console.log("Formated Token:", my_formated_token); 

          var my_headers = "{'Authorization': '" + my_formated_token + "'}";
          console.log("My Headers:", my_headers);
                  });  

 //lets execute the callback from an agent
  queuecallback({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://myapi.com/go',
          data: {
        phoneNumber: '1111111111',
        skill: '12345'
            },
       headers: my_headers              
  }
        )
        .then((result) => {
                  console.log("your contactId is:", result.data.contactId);
                  }); 
      }  

});
```

Comment: One, you are setting your `my_headers` variable inside the `then()` callback which wont be called by the time `queuecallback()` is called. Two you have `var my_headers =` the use of `var` here makes that variable local, ie it isnt the same variable that is declared in the outer scope. Setting it doesnt change the outer scope variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necesseray to require two axios :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const queuecallback = require('axios');
```

Your problem is that you set the headers in the first call

`var my_headers = "{'Authorization': '" + my_formated_token + "'}";`

axios is a asynchronous function so the `queuecallback` is called directly after the first `axios` call (which is not finished). You can use async function to "wait" the end of the first call :

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function connectToAgentHandler(agent) {
  try {
    let result = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://myapi.com/AuthorizationServer/Token',
      data: {
        username: 'myusername',
        password: 'mypassword',
        grant_type: 'password'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'basic 123456789Aghtiaqq111kkksksksk111'
      }
    });

    const token = `bearer ${result.data.access_token}`;

    const headers = {
      'Authorization': token
    };

    result = axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://myapi.com/go',
      data: {
        phoneNumber: '1111111111',
        skill: '12345'
      },
      headers
    });

    console.log("your contactId is:", result.data.contactId);
  } catch (err) {
    // process error
  }
};
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you so much for taking the time to correct my code.